# Waiting for result in IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

Is there a way to wait for the result when using IntentService?

Scenario.

Service App is running --> receives login credentials from another app --> Service app then checks database (for some reason I always get Connection time out. And I know this is bad but for POC and a quick hack this will do for now) --> Wait for validation query then results.

Is this possible?

I tried using AsynTask inside the Service but still to no avail, I always get Connection timeout error.

DEMOSERVICE

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return new IDemoService.Stub() {

        @Override
        /**
         * Login validation implementation
         */
        public boolean login(String id, String password)
                throws RemoteException {
            UserLoginTask userLoginTask = new UserLoginTask(id, password);
            try {
                return userLoginTask.execute((Void) null).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

USERLOGINTASK

```
 private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private String uId;
    private String uPassword;

    public UserLoginTask(String id, String password) {
        uId = id;
        uPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Connection conn;
        try {
            int count = 0;
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/test_db?user=postgres&password=password";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (conn != null) {
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "Select count(*) as cnt from tbl_persons where id = '"
                        + uId.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()).trim()
                        + "' AND pwd='" + uPassword.trim() + "';";

                Log.d("DemoService", "Login sql - " + sql);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    count = rs.getInt("cnt");
                }

                rs.close();
                st.close();
                conn.close();

                if (count == 0)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: you question is not very clear, can you post some code also

Comment: Hi. I added a sample code. I get an error every time getConnection(url) happens. I tried to put connectionTimeout but there is still an error. I am looking at IntentService however I don't know if it can wait for the proper result.

Comment: How you are using postgresql in android, you should use sqlite

Comment: I know. But a system is in place all i have to do is validate to that table. no ws or rest server.

Comment: Seems, the question is 'Why do You get Connection Timeout', but not 'Waiting for result in IntentService'. And where's no need for AsyncTask, because IntentService already 'handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work'.

Comment: But is there a way to do this with IntentService -->  return userLoginTask.execute((Void) null).get(); ? Or you have to use Handler or BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: I think a BroadcastReceiver is the normal way of doing this.